# Wordpress page with Categories

Tags: wordpress

i wonna to create a page with list of all categories, for my template.

But i can't find the way how i can do this.

Maybe I have to add a new file in my template folder?

Thx

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Template Tags/wp list categories « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for the function and code examples. You'll want to make a page template to use that function on its own page: [Page Templates « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)